# With HTML and JS when I try to set a <h1> value nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html

I call this JS function every 10 seconds, but nothing happens. When typing this exact same piece of code into the JS console in Chrome, I get the desired result. What is going on?

```js
document.getElementById("mesText").innerHTML = ("Message (" + "Estimated cost: " + ((375 + document.getElementById("MessageBox").value.length * 8 + document.getElementById("name").value.length * 8)) + " Gas)");
```

```html
 <label for="mes" class="col-lg-2 control-label" id="mesText">
Message
</label>
```

Comment: Please add the element with the ID `MessageBox` to the Snippet!

Comment: And the element with the ID `name`.

Comment: Title suggests an `<h1>` value but there is no `<h1>` shown in the html and an h1 doesn't have `value`. Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces the issue

Comment: Why would the price of something depend on the *length* of input values?

Comment: @Barmar It is not literal gas. It is the estimated cost of a transaction in the ethereum blockchain. It is not actually buying something.

Comment: @CalW But why is the estimate based on `.value.length`?

Comment: @Barmar Essentially, I am writing a string to the blockchain. This costs gas. Gas is essentially a very small amount of money. The more text we write the more gas we need to pay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want to update that part after message in `span` not `h1` since there is no such element in code that you have posted. I have tried your code and it works. Check if you have elements with ids: `MessageBox`
and `name` in your html file since that code is getting their value.

Also note that elements with mentioned ids can't be just arbitrary html elements, but those that actually have a `value` property associated with them. Otherwise you will get an error since you are using `value.length` which can't be used in such case (`value` would be `undefined`, and `undefined` doesn't have `length` property).

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', event => {
  document.getElementById("mesText").innerHTML = ("Message (" + "Estimated cost: " + ((375 + document.getElementById("MessageBox").value.length * 8 + document.getElementById("name").value.length * 8)) + " Gas)");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input id='MessageBox' />
<button>submit</button>

<label for="mes" class="col-lg-2 control-label" id="mesText">
  Message: 
</label>
```

And I would suggest to do some refactoring of your code because it is really not that readable which also makes it harder to test. You can do
a little modification and check the output of `console.log` to see if you are 
getting the correct elements.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const output = document.getElementById("mesText");
const messageBox = document.getElementById("MessageBox");
const name = document.getElementById("name");

console.log(messageBox);
console.log(name);

btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  output.innerHTML = ("Message (" + "Estimated cost: " + ((375 +
    messageBox.value.length * 8 + name.value.length * 8)) + " Gas)");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input id='MessageBox' />
<button>submit</button>

<label for="mes" class="col-lg-2 control-label" id="mesText">
  Message: 
</label>
```

Comment: What you said about length does not seem to be accurate. When I run `document.getElementById("MessageBox").value` I get a string. Therefore, when I do the `.length` of that I would get the length of the string.

Comment: @CalW Try `console.log(document.querySelector('p').value.length);` with some `p` element and you will see the error.

Comment: I got your code working with a little tweaking. I changed it from `btn.addEventListener....` to be its own function, and made that function be called using `onclick` in the buttons tags. I think yours might not work because I have multiple buttons.

Comment: @CalW Sure, if you have multiple buttons then you need to select the specific one or modify it a little bit. This was just an example. I am glad you have it working.